# Xml attribute value not displaying in python dataframe output

Tags: python, xml

```
import pandas as pdf
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


treefl = et.parse('429411newsML.xml')
treeroot = treefl.getroot()
news_title = treefl.find("title").text

itemids = treef1.find("newsitem")
if itemids is not None:
  item_id = itemids.get['itemid']
else:
  item_id = None
```

In the above code, i am trying to get the value of an attribute in an xml file where the tags name is 'newsitem' and the attribute name is 'itemid'.

When i'm trying to insert item_id in my pandas dataframe using the code mentioned below, only None shows up in the dataframe and if i happened to not put in the else statement, 'item_id' is not defined shows up. If i try to use attrib[] instead of get , that doesnt do the trick either.

```
    rows.append({"title" : news_title, "text" : node.text, "bip:topics" : news_codes_class, "dc.date.published" : news_date_published, "item_id" : item_id})
```

I had no problem extracting other fields from the xml file but just this field seems to have this issue. Below is a snippet of the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<newsitem itemid="429411" id="root" date="1997-03-10" xml:lang="en">
<title>EU:  OFFICIAL JOURNAL CONTENTS - OJ L 66 OF MARCH 6, 1997.</title>
```

Comment: Please upload a valid xml snippet

Comment: @balderman im sorry but i managed to solve the issue.